# Create procedure with a insert statement in Oracle pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I am trying to create procedure with this insert statement which otherwise working fine but when trying to incorporate this insert query into the procedure it giving me below error

```
Error(11,1): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored and 
Error(16,17): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "DBMS_RANDOM"."VALUE": invalid identifier
```

I need to run this proc for 10 months in order to replicate the data for 10 month in a loop, but I am stuck on step one, and proc is not getting compiled.

```
{
    create or replace PROCEDURE datareplicationProcedure
    (Start_date IN Date, End_date IN Date) AS 
    
    
    
     BEGIN

        `insert statement`
    insert into SAM_CDS.transactions
(TENANT_CD,TRANSACTION_KEY, BATCH_ID ,ACCT_CURR_AMOUNT, BATCH_DATE_TIME,DAY_SK,WEEK_SK, MONTH_SK )
    (
    Select A.TENANT_CD, A.TRANSACTION_KEY,A.BATCH_ID,A.acct_curr_amount,A.BATCH_DATE_TIME,D.DAY_SK,D.WEEK_SK, D.MONTH_SK
    from (
    ( select TENANT_CD,'TRANSACTION_'||(DBMS_RANDOM.string('x',10))as TRANSACTION_KEY,BATCH_ID,acct_curr_amount ,
    TO_DATE( TRUNC( DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(TO_CHAR(DATE '2021-07-01','J'),TO_CHAR(DATE '2021-07-31','J'))),'J') BATCH_DATE_TIME
    from SAM_CDS.transactions where batch_date_time 
    between to_date('04-FEB-19') and to_Date('05-FEB-19')
    )A
    left outer join 
    (select * from SAM_CDS.DAY where DATETIME between Start_date and End_date)D
    on D.DATETIME=A.BATCH_DATE_TIME )
);

     END datareplicationProcedure;
}
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that the owner of the procedure has not been given access to the `dbms_random` package via a direct grant.  If the `insert` statement compiles outside of a stored procedure, the grant was most likely through a role rather than through a direct grant.  Definer's rights stored procedures cannot make use of privileges granted through a role only those privileges that are granted directly to the user.  You could change the procedure to be an invoker's rights stored procedure which can use permissions granted through a role but that would require that the role was available to the caller in every session where the procedure is invoked.  More likely, you want to ask your DBA to grant access to the `dbms_random` to the procedure owner directly.

Comment: Thanks Justin , you are right , I asked DBA team to give permission with grant option and it worked.

Comment: Now i am facing other issue, the date i am passing in the proc , i want to use in DBAM_RANDOM function , but its giving me error of missing expression.

Comment: TO_DATE( TRUNC( DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(TO_CHAR(DATE (Start_date),'J'),TO_CHAR(DATE (End_date),'J'))),'J')

Comment: @shweta - I don't understand what `date(start_date)` and `date(end_date)` are supposed to represent.  There is no `date` function.  You could mean `to_date` but that would only make sense if you were passing in a string.  Your procedure declaration indicates that you are passing in a date so it makes no sense to cast the parameter to the same data type.

Comment: thank you again Justin :) i was doing a silly mistake which you mentioned correctly, it accepted the parameter when i remove the date part from the function . officially this is my 1st stored proc , now i am going add a loop in this proc to run it for 10 month , wish me luck :)